# hottest questions by tag is found by google search

Tags: discussion, bug, seo

I search on google for: "autofac nested ienumerable flatten" and found:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/namevaluecollection/hot

The page contains a lot of terms that are very loosly related, misguiding me, because the answer on my question is definitely not on that page...

I would think these kind of pages should not be indexed by google or at least by using `<section>` so that google knows what is going on at that page.